# The google maps in my home page become blank when the application reopened from the background

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-maps, fluttermap

I use `Google Maps` in my Flutter app and when I make my app in the background state and reopen the screen , the map becomes blank.

Here is the code of the map

```
Container(
    child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
     GoogleMap(

              zoomControlsEnabled: true,
              initialCameraPosition:initialCameraPosition,

              mapType: MapType.normal,
              markers: markers,
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller){
                googleMapController = controller;
                googleMapController = controller;
                _mapController = controller;
                // _controller = controller;
                _conntroller.complete(controller);

              },


            ),
```